# Z error detection circuit

Tags: error-correction

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wTaFd7nqbtQ) at 0:50, they have two circuits. One claims to detect a Z error in any of four qubits and one detects an X error in any of the four qubits. I don't understand the Z error detection circuit.

[image]

The ancilla qubit is the control for the CNOT gate so how does it know if the target of the CNOT had a Z error or not?

I thought first there is an error in the figure but the rest of the video suggests that this is not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let qubit $p$ be the parity qubit i.e., control qubit of the $CNOT$.
Let qubit $t$ be the target qubit

The $CNOT$ works as follows:

$$CNOT_{p\to t} \bigg[|+\rangle_p |+\rangle_t\bigg] = |+\rangle_p |+\rangle_t\,.$$
Here, when there is no error on our "target" qubit, measuring the parity qubit after the $H$, will give you $H|+\rangle_p = |0\rangle_p \,,$ and you will conclude that there was no $Z$ error on your target qubit.

But if your target qubit had $Z$ error, then it will make $|+\rangle_t \xrightarrow{Z} |-\rangle_t.$ Then the parity check will give you:

$$CNOT_{p\to t} \bigg[|+\rangle_p |-\rangle_t\bigg] = |-\rangle_p |-\rangle_t\,,$$

and thus, measuring the parity qubit after the $H$, will give you $H|-\rangle_p = |1\rangle_p\,,$ and you will conclude that there was a $Z$ error on your target qubit.